# php artisan stuck if you have another php artisan running in background

Tags: php, laravel

Yes, I have detected that php artisan is stuck if I have another php artisan running in backgroup.  For example I run: php artisan horizon & and then trying to php artisan migrate or just php artisan to bring whole list of options didnt work.  Just freeze until I stop php artisan horizon.   And then I can work with php artisan migrate.  Any idea of what's happening? I'm using docker image php:8-apache.  I wonder it could be related to php.  I will tell you if I found out what is.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was PHPStorm listening to debug, because I have XDebug to connect to my computer always.

```
xdebug.client_host=mycomputer
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.start_with_request=1
xdebug.discover_client_host=0
xdebug.client_port=9001
```

I disabled PHPStorm listening for PHP Debug Connections and problem solved.

Comment: But if it was not hitting a breakpoint why was it stopped?

Comment: @MarshallDavis PHPStorm has a connection limit. It seems like xdebug (or PHPStorm?) is halting execution until the limit is no longer satisfied. If you raise the limit. It should work perfectly fine.